# Do I have to store return values from methods C#

Tags: c#

I just started working with C# and I have noticed that my code works even if I 
don't store a return value from a method. Example: Lets say I have a method

```
public class Hello(){
    public bool GoodMorning(){
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then this works:

```
Hello.GoodMorning();
```

- What happens to the return value that I never store?
- Is is bad practice to not store the return value?
- If so, why?

Comment: Sometimes a method returns something and you don't care about what it returns and thus there is no need to capture the return value.

Comment: Your code is legal, but it also means that you don't know whether it returned `true` or `false`. Sometimes you don't care, sometimes this is important info.

Comment: Values returned from a method that are not stored in the caller method are doomed to wonder the ghost world untill getting killed by the clr. Your code is perfectly valid.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know any language that would require to store the function return value. It is just optional.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys :) I see it is marked as a duplicate and that my question already had an answer. Do I delete this question then, or just leave it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It simply wont capture the value. Nothing bad happens to it. Sometimes return values may not be important to you, and are only there if you wish to access the status or production from it. Even if it did capture the variable, it would treat it like all locals are treated and be disposed once the scope is exited.

Answer (score 0):

> What happens to the return value that I never store?

It gets discarded.

> Is is bad practice to not store the return value?

No, not really. Sometimes we are do not use the value returned.

Answer (score 0):

> What happens to the return value that I never store

They all live together in a little house dedicated to ignored return values. No, seriously, the same as happens to all non-referenced objects (garbage collection etc).

> Is is bad practice to not store the return value?

Not really. Sometimes a method returns something that you're just not interested in, and in which case its fine to ignore them